# SVM using cosine kernel - dataset with images of dogs and cats

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, cosine-similarity

Hello I am trying to implement SVM by using cosine kernel but I can't undertand how  I can do this..

What i thought it was the following, but i think its wrong

```
svmCosine = cosine_similarity(train_X, train_y)
svmCosine.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer to my question is the following

```
svmCosine= svm.SVC(kernel = cosine_similarity(train_X, train_y))
svmCosine.fit(train_X, train_y)
```